# List of available WiFi networks for android 10+

Tags: android, kotlin, wifi

Somehow different apps for smart devices(light bulbs, baby monitors etc.) are able to show custom screen with list of available WiFi networks.
How is it possible to achieve?

I know that Starting from Android 10 (API level 29), the

```
WifiManager.startScan()
```

method has been deprecated. And it is no longer possible to get a list of all available WiFi networks directly.

Comment: are you saying that none of the suggestions reported here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan work?

Answer (score 0):

If something is deprecated on android, it means you should look to use alternative methods when provided. No alternative has been provided as of yet. This means that the current startScan() is the only way to scan wifi networks.

As documented by Android, [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan), you must do the following to get the scan results

```
val wifiManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager

val wifiScanReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {

  override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    val success = intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED, false)
    if (success) {
      scanSuccess()
    } else {
      scanFailure()
    }
  }
}

val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)
context.registerReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, intentFilter)

val success = wifiManager.startScan()
if (!success) {
  // scan failure handling
  scanFailure()
}

....

private fun scanSuccess() {
  val results = wifiManager.scanResults
  ... use new scan results ...
}

private fun scanFailure() {
  // handle failure: new scan did NOT succeed
  // consider using old scan results: these are the OLD results!
  val results = wifiManager.scanResults
  ... potentially use older scan results ...
}
```